# Variable change inside Perl subroutine

Tags: perl

I’m new to Perl programming, and was trying to pass a single parameter in a Perl subroutine and modify it within the subroutine. The problem is, inside the subroutine, the variable still retains its original value. Only when it is returned, and gets out of the subroutine, it reflects its new/changed value.

```
    @arr1 = qw(166 2 3 4);
    $a, $b, $c, $d;
    ($a, $b, $c, $d) = @arr1;
    $mnop = &oneparam("$a");
    print "mnop returned from oneparam is :", $mnop, "\n";

    sub oneparam{

         $qrst = shift;
         print "param passed is ", $qrst, "\n";
         $qsrt = 166 + 1;
         print "qrst inside method ", $qrst, "\n";
        return $qsrt;
  }
  print "qsrt outside method, ", $qsrt, "\n";
```

it gives the following o/p:

```
param passed is 166
**qrst inside method 166**
mnop returned from oneparam is :167
qsrt outside method, 167
```

The line in bold(qrst...166) should have been 167. Can someone please help me understand why its 166?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't scope any of your variables. You should be declaring your variables with `my` to limit their scope.

Always use `use strict; use warnings;`. One of the things this does it give an error when you forget to declare a variable.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub oneparam {
     my $qrst = shift;
     $qsrt = $qrst + 1;
     return $qsrt;
}

for my $n (qw(166 2 3 4)) {
    my $mnop = oneparam($n);
    print "oneparam($a) = $mnop\n";
}
```

Comment: While your answer points the way towards finding the problem, it doesn't actually point out what the problem was (a typo `$qrst` vs. `$qsrt`).

Comment: @amon, I missed that part of the question. Then again, `use strict;` will find that error, so I'm  good :)

Comment: @amon thanks a ton for pointing out the type